# sklearn.impute fit() function

Tags: python, scikit-learn

i am reading *Python for Data Science for Dummies* (2nd ed.), on chapter 6, at *Imputing Missing Data* section. The book shows a sample code using **scikit-learn** library.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, np.NaN, 5, 6, None])
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
imp.fit([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

I tried to understand the code line-by-line so I read the `fit(X)` documentation on sklearn's website. However, it just says

> fit the imputer on X

and i don't understand this. then upon further reading i found this

> Before you can impute anything, you must provide **statistics** for the Imputer to use by calling fit()

which i don't understand too

So my question is: what does the word 'statistics' mean? thanks

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleImputer` is used to fill `nan` values based on the strategy parameter (by using the `mean` or the `median` feature value, the `most_frequent` value or a `constant`).

`fit()` function will calculate the statistic that depends on your strategy.

For example, if `strategy='mean'`. The fit function will calculate the mean based on the `X` dataset.

Once this is done, the imputer can be used to fill value on a dataset as follow.

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
import numpy as np
X_train = np.array([0,0, np.nan, 1, 1]).reshape((-1,1))

SimpleImputer(strategy='mean').fit_transform(X_train)
```

Output:

```
array([[0. ],
       [0. ],
       [0.5],
       [1. ],
       [1. ]])
```

Note that you can perform both `fit()` and `transform()` operation with `fit_transform()`.